# What does # mean in ASP.NET VB?

Tags: vb.net

This statement appears in code I am trying to work on. I do not understand what the # is for at the beginning of the line:

```
    #If DEBUG Then
        EventsLog.WriteToEventLog("Service Starting (version: " & versionNumber.ToString & ")", ProductNameClass.Name, EventLogEntryType.Information, EventId.DebugStart)

    #Else
        EventsLog.WriteToEventLog("Service Starting (version: " & versionNumber.ToString & ")", ProductNameClass.Name, EventLogEntryType.Information, EventId.Starting)
    #End If
```

Answer (score 2):

**What is #?**
 #(Hash) is called [Preprocessor Directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx)

**What is  #If...Then...#Else?**
On the surface, the behavior of the #If...Then...#Else directives appears the same as that of the If...Then...Else statements. However, the #If...Then...#Else directives evaluate what is compiled by the compiler, whereas the If...Then...Else statements evaluate conditions at run time.

This Condition compiles the 1st statement if you are in debug mode otherwise it compiles the 2nd statement.

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx6yas69.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

They are compile directives.  When you run your project in Debug mode, the first statement will run.  If you run it in any other mode, such as Release, the second statement will run.

Answer (score 1):

Its called [preprocessor directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/3sxhs2ty.aspx). If compilation symbol (in your case DEBUG) is defined during compilation, the first branch will make it into the built code, if not the second branch will. DEBUG symbol is by default defined if you build your project in DEBUG mode.